# Are there any game engines out there that support cryptography?

Tags: encryption

Are there any game engines out there that support cryptography? Obviously when one creates a game engine in one of the more established languages, like C++ or Java, one can just get some cryptography libraries and use those. I'm mainly asking about engines that allow one to create games using mainly a scripting language like lua or javascript.

Comment: Support cryptography for what?  What do you want to have encrypted?

Comment: @NathanReed At the moment my list of requirements is sha256, secp256k1, ripemd160, as well as some private-public key encryption/decryption and commutative encryption/decryption. Mostly the encryption will done on a short strings of data to represent various parts of a card game.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the presence of crypto isn't the only thing that's part of your evaluation of game engines.  My suggestion would be to start making a list of features you require (including crypto), and start whittling down the list of engines.

Additionally, what you want to do with it is a factor as well.  If you just want to encrypt a local file, that's going to be pretty easy perhaps.  If you want to encrypt data transmission between your client and a server, that's getting more complex.  But at the same time client/server encryption is pretty common, including just using HTTPS.

Also note that a quick Google shows libraries do exist, including ones for JavaScript and Lua.